# Problem when attaching strings, making it wrap around Java

Tags: java, string

I have this variable that I assign to using:

```
String[] lineSplit = line.split(" ");
String output = lineSplit[4];
```

When I use `System.out.println(output)` it outputs: `z` (which it gets from the string). But when I print `System.out.println(output + ".")`, it outputs: `.`.

I did some more tests, like: `System.out.println("Output " + output + ".")`, and it outputs: `.utput z`

I have no idea what is causing this and I don't know what to search to find the error.

More information:

- The text is read from a file (so may be an encoding issue?)
- Checks against it (using `==` and `.equals`) don't work
- Adding more characters on the end of `System.out.println(output + ".")` replaces more characters at the start
- There are no errors or warnings (using IntelliJ)

Comment: what was the value of 'line' variable

Comment: it looks like `output` contains multi-byte characters that don't play nice with ascii. What does `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.getBytes()))` print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that `output` contains the string:

```
"z\r"
```

The key thing here is that it contains a single carriage return character (CR/`\r`) in it. This could be meant as a new line in some OSs (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) for the OSs that use CR as a new line). Given that the string came from a file, this seems entirely possible.

To verify this, loop through the string and see if you find a `\r` character:

```
int cr = '\r';
boolean found = output.chars().anyMatch(x -> x == cr);
System.out.println(found);
```

It could also be helpful if you print every element of `output.chars()`, so you know exactly what's in `output`, and we don't have to guess :)

Anyway, my macOS Terminal (and probably whatever console you are using as well) *doesn't* treat CR as a new line, and instead moves the cursor to the start of the current line, behaving like a typewriter. Hence, the characters after the `\r` overwrites the characters at the start of the line.

OTOH, my IntelliJ console just deletes everything before the CR when it sees any characters after it, so it really depends on what console you use.

Comment: That was it. The code returned true everytime there was a new line, and when I removed then it worked fine! Thanks.